# Reported PPI of jpeg image conflicts between Imagemagick & GIMP

Tags: resolution, images, gimp, imagemagick

I have a jpeg image and I wish to find out the image resolution in PPI before sending it to someone.

I open it in GIMP 2 (on Ubuntu Studio 20.04) and look at the image properties.
It reports a resolution of 72x72 ppi. (Preview on macOS reports the same)
See [screenshot of image properties dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZgle.png)

However if I use the `identify` command from the Imagemagick package I get a different report.

The command
`identify -units PixelsPerInch -format '%[resolution.x] x %[resolution.y] %[units]\n' A4\ portrait\ NMP.jpg` reports `300 x 300 PixelsPerInch`

Why is there a discrepancy?
Which should I believe?

Thanks

Comment: PPI only ever matters when you actually Print something, or use page layout software. Until then all an image has is dimensions in pixels. DPI/PPI are merely hints to a page layout app & not absolute.

Comment: There are multiple metadata formats. They may have conflicting data. You can probably view them somehow in GIMP, or, if that doesn't work, definitely with ExifTool.

Answer (score 0):

PPI - Pixels per inch.

Say that you have an image which is 3000 by 2000 pixels with 24 bit color depth (say a 6MP [megapixel] JPG file, as produced by an old Nikon D40).
If you print that image to be ten inches wide, then you have a 300 PPI PRINTED image.

*A side note here: the PRINTER may need an 8x8 DOT matrix to produce the COLOR of a single IMAGE PIXEL; 8x300 = 2400 DPI, DOTS per inch*

Any "PPI"-number presented INSIDE the JPG-file, is just garbage in that situation.

Now look at the print size reported in your screenshot. Printed at 72 PPI it would end up almost a meter wide (847mm, 33+ inches). As 72 PPI is a fairly LOW resolution image (as printed) it would appear to have "jagged" edges (if any in image) when viewed up close.
That, if anything, tells that the number is just "garbage"; it has no relation to how you normally use the image; unless you **actuallý intend** to print it at that size.

NOTE: Using GIMP's "Scale Image" you can set the "PPI" to whatever you like. It will not change anything else about the image; some "garbage" software will use the value for random things though *(e.g. automatic pixel scaling related to the display resolution)*.